# How can I build in KDevelop a Ninja project without using CMake?

Tags: cmake, ninja, kdevelop, meson-build

CMake can generate a Ninja configured project, which can then be built from KDevelop.

However I already get my Ninja files with another tool (Meson).

How can I make KDevelop use the Ninja files I provide, without calling CMake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way other than using `Custom buildsystem` plugin yet. So, eiter use CMake build system with Ninja generator, or custom buildsystem.

But the good news are that Meson plugin for KDevelop is already being baked and hopefully will see a release!

Comment: I cannot call Meson from KDevelop, yet, but, once I have the Ninja files from it, I can now run the custom build. To opt for a custom build, I had to delete the old KDevelop project file, and create a new one.